# Where should I put shared methods for Delayed Job?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, refactoring, delayed-job

I have some Delayed::Job classes under app/jobs/. I have some methods that are the same for some of this jobs and I need to refactor my app creating a module containing this shared methods, that will be required in the jobs.

It's popular to create an "app/lib" directory, so it autoloaded by default, but this code has very little to do with the rails app and only belongs to the background job so I think it shouldn't belong here.

Also I think it doesn't belong to "app/jobs" either, since it's not a job but just a library... This leaves me with some other possibilities such as "app/jobs/lib/", or "app/jobs/concerns/" or simply "/lib/".

What is the common way to store this file?

Comment: I don't believe there is any standard but `app/jobs/concerns/` sounds like a great choice because analogy will be instantly clear to anyone looking at the dir structure.